# Where is the (original) proof of Klaus Potthoff's Theorem about the order type of arithmetic models?

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic, peano-axioms, nonstandard-models

I am looking for a complete proof, respectively for the complete original proof of the following theorem, which is attributed to Klaus Potthoff:

> If $\mathfrak{M}$ is a nonstandard model of PA, then it cannot have the order type $\mathbb{N} + \mathbb{Z} \cdot \mathbb{R}$.

In the PhD thesis of Bovykin (2000) there is a reference to Smorynski (1984), which refers itself to Pothoff. What I've found so far is a [sketch](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~kach/mathematics/slides1may2004.pdf), but I am not sure, if that belongs to the original proof.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It might be in his Habilitationsschrift, Univ. of Kiel, 1972, [*Über Enderweiterungen von Nichtstandardmodellen der Arithmetik und anderer Strukturen*](http://d-nb.info/741005883) (*On end extensions of non-standard models of arithmetic and other structures*), if you can find a copy.

Comment: The proof that Asher Kach wrote up is more than a sketch, despite him labeling it as such.  Is there something in that argument that is causing trouble?

Comment: @Heywood Thank you for the pointer to Kach's slides! Nice short proof. +1

Comment: @Brian: Thanks, I just ordered a copy from the library. When I receive it, I will post my findings, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original proof of Potthoff's theorem can be found in his paper "[Über Nichtstandardmodelle der Arithmetik und der rationalen Zahlen](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/malq.19690151304/abstract)" from 1969. Let $\omega + \zeta \cdot \theta$ with $\omega$ the order type of $\mathbb{N}$ and $\zeta$ the order type of $\mathbb{Z}$. Then we have:

> **Satz 1.2:** $\theta$ ist ein offener, dichter Ordnungstyp, der kein stetiges Stück mit mehr als einem Element enthält.

Translation: $\theta$ is an boundlessly and dense order type, which has no continuous part with more than one element. Therefore $\theta$ cannot be the order type of $\mathbb{R}$.

The proof uses Dedekind cuts and therefore differs from the mentioned sketch. If someone is interested I'll translate the original proof from German to English right here.

Comment: I found the reference for the mentioned paper in Potthoff's Habilitationsschrift where it is named as "Satz 1.1" at page 10.